# AC/DC SMPS- How to do PWM

Tags: power-supply, pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, buck

[image]

I'm trying to design and build a simple ac/dc smps that outputs 5v dc and capable of 2 amps. I currently have some of it designed but the problem I'm running into now is how to get a pwm signal with 18V when I go to build it as I have simulated? Do you have any suggestions? Maybe there are some ic's on the market that can do the pwm with feedback circuitry so the output voltage always stays ~5v dc? I desperately need help with this as I need to build it soon to stay on track for my project. Thanks for all your help.

The transformer is a 10:1 and the 18V Square wave is at ~40% duty cycle at the gate

Comment: That'll be a crappy buck regulator for sure - you should consider a P ch mosfet as the switching transistor else you'll always be having to hit the gate with a signal that is significantly bigger than the output voltage you need.

Comment: Using N-channel is unnecessary complication here. Take a look into crusty old TL494's datasheet, it has the exact circuit you need.

Comment: I only choose a NMOS because I couldn't get the PMOS to work on my simulation. Maybe I was using the wrong voltage into the gate?

Comment: The TL494 does all the pwm circuitry I need including feedback which will help adjust the duty cycle of the pwm? Can I use it in my design that I have above? Do I need to change anything?

Answer (score 3):

This should really be a comment since this is mostly a shopping question, but seeing how you've asked this like 3-4 times...

[Poweresim](http://www.poweresim.com/) is a reasonable way to get something whipped up (using TL494) when you are as inexperienced as you are with SMPS. Or use one of the easier (but more expensive) chips from various mfg. Most have their own on-line tools for doing a quick spec [just with their own chips usually]. Since you seem to have trouble finding them, here are a few:

- TI: [web-based "Webench"](http://www.ti.com/lsds/ti/analog/webench/power.page) (registration req. for simulation) and [downloadable](http://www.ti.com/tool/powerstage-designer)
- Fairchild: [on-line  Power Supply WebDesigner](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/design/design-tools/#powersupply) and [downloadable](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/design/design-tools/smps-fairchild-power-switch-design-tools/) (registration req.)
- NXP: http://nxp.transim.com/
- Linear: [LTpowerCAD](http://www.linear.com/solutions/1159)
- ON: [GreenPoint](https://www.onsemi.com/PowerSolutions/content.do?id=18415)
- Analog Devices: [ADIsimPower](http://www.analog.com/en/design-center/advanced-selection-and-design-tools/interactive-design-tools/adisimpower.html)
- ST: [eDesignSuite](http://www.st.com/web/en/support/eDesign_Suite.html?sc=edesignsuite) (registration req.)
- Maxim: [EE-SIM](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/ee_sim/index.mvp?) (registration req.)

Avnet has a nice list: [Avnet - Power Simulation Design Tools by Supplier](http://www.em.avnet.com/en-us/design/markets-technologies/power/Pages/Power-Simulation-Design-Tools-by-Supplier.aspx)

There is a longer list: [Power Electronics Design Simulation Analysis Tools at PowerGuru.org](http://www.powerguru.org/power-electronics-design-simulation-analysis-tools)

Alas it has proven difficult to find a recent [comparative] review of these on-line tools. I found [one from 2004](http://www.designnews.com/document.asp?doc_id=214848), which is very dated.

And for recommendation on more in-depth/background material: [Reddit - Good Resources for Learning SMPS Design for ACDC](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskElectronics/comments/31crdr/good_resources_for_learning_smps_design_for_acdc/)

Comment: Regardless of how poor the board layout, or little attention is paid to the filter components, Linear Tech SMPS parts just work.